# Is there any way to pass the password to pam_start() or pam_authenticate() and bypass the "conversation"?

Tags: authentication, pam

pam_start() takes a parameter that is a structure ( http://linux.die.net/man/3/pam_conv ) where you can set a callback method for getting the password.  Since I already have the password before my call to pam_start, I was wondering if there was a way to pass that information instead of setting up the callback.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently, there is not a way.

But see my work-around at https://stackoverflow.com/a/5970078/55944

Comment: sorry for the downvote, I clicked too fast, now stackoverflow doesn't let me take it back

Comment: @ammoQ: I have read downvote 'message' above, so I am upvoting (of a correct answer anyway.)

Comment: Fortunately, I've been able to upvote now, so my debt is repaid :)