# How to authenticate username/password using PAM w/o root privileges

Tags: linux, authentication, pam

I have program written in C. It takes 2 arguments username/password and try to authenticate this user using PAM. It works fine when I'm root. When I'm 'normal' user, it works for this user, but not for another one. I think, it's due to using shadow passwords..

As service I'm using:

```
retval = pam_start("test", username, &local_conversation, &local_auth_handle);
```

I add this to the /etc/pam.d/test

```
#%PAM-1.0
auth    required    pam_unix.so shadow nullok
account required    pam_unix.so
session required    pam_unix.so
```

Could you help me, please?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: I found one solution: chmod 444 /etc/shadow.. but: is it safe??

Comment: The obvious answer to your question about safety is: NO!

Comment: I resolved this issue. Check my site http://vkrejcirik.info/2012/06/09/authentication-in-c-through-pam-in-linux/

Comment: I imagine it's unsafe because PAM would allow unchecked brute-forcing of passwords.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The application needed to be able to read `/etc/shadow`.

See [my post](http://vkrejcirik.info/2012/06/09/authentication-in-c-through-pam-in-linux/) for one way to do this.

EDIT:
Add post from above link in case the link ever breaks

> I wrote authentication module in C++ which alows to check
>   username/password through PAM in Linux (I’m using Fedora Linux). I
>   would like to share with you, what I made :-) . So, let’s go :-)
>
> Prerequisities:
>
> ```
> Install package pam-devel
> (This step is necessary when you use shadow password) Create new Linux user and group. Set this group as default for this user. Then
> ```
>
> follow with these steps:
>           Go to /etc
>           Log in as root (su)
>           Change group to the new one for file shadow (chgrp new_group shadow)
>           Set ‘read’ privilage for this group (chmod 0440 shadow)
>
> Write this code: (authModule.c) view plaincopy to clipboardprint?
>
> ```
> #include <stdio.h>  
> #include <security/pam_appl.h>  
> #include <unistd.h>  
> #include <stdlib.h>  
> #include <string.h>  
>
> struct pam_response *reply;  
>
> // //function used to get user input  
> int function_conversation(int num_msg, const struct pam_message **msg, struct pam_response **resp, void *appdata_ptr)  
> {  
>     *resp = reply;  
>         return PAM_SUCCESS;  
> }  
>
> int authenticate_system(const char *username, const char *password)   
> {  
>     const struct pam_conv local_conversation = { function_conversation, NULL };  
>     pam_handle_t *local_auth_handle = NULL; // this gets set by pam_start  
>
>     int retval;  
>     retval = pam_start("su", username, &local_conversation, &local_auth_handle);  
>
>     if (retval != PAM_SUCCESS)  
>     {  
>             printf("pam_start returned: %d\n ", retval);  
>             return 0;  
>     }  
>
>     reply = (struct pam_response *)malloc(sizeof(struct pam_response));  
>
>     reply[0].resp = strdup(password);  
>     reply[0].resp_retcode = 0;  
>     retval = pam_authenticate(local_auth_handle, 0);  
>
>     if (retval != PAM_SUCCESS)  
>     {  
>             if (retval == PAM_AUTH_ERR)  
>             {  
>                     printf("Authentication failure.\n");  
>             }  
>             else  
>             {  
>                 printf("pam_authenticate returned %d\n", retval);  
>             }  
>             return 0;  
>     }  
>
>     printf("Authenticated.\n");  
>     retval = pam_end(local_auth_handle, retval);  
>
>     if (retval != PAM_SUCCESS)  
>     {  
>             printf("pam_end returned\n");  
>             return 0;  
>     }  
>
>     return 1;  
> }  
>
> int main(int argc, char** argv)  
> {  
>     char* login;  
>     char* password;  
>
>     printf("Authentication module\n");  
>
>     if (argc != 3)  
>     {  
>         printf("Invalid count of arguments %d.\n", argc);  
>         printf("./authModule <username> <password>");  
>         return 1;  
>     }  
>
>     login = argv[1];  
>     password = argv[2];  
>
>     if (authenticate_system(login, password) == 1)  
>     {  
>         printf("Authenticate with %s - %s through system\n", login, password);  
>         return 0;  
>     }     
>
>     printf("Authentication failed!\n");  
>     return 1;  
> }
> ```
>
> Compile code:
>
> ```
> gcc -o authModule authModule.c -lpam
> ```
>
> Run code (as the new user!):
>
> ```
> ./authModule user password
> ```
>
> That’s all!! :-) Hope it helps!

Comment: Doesn't work if run as root user.

Answer (score 1):

I yet cannot comment on the post of Vladislav due to too low rep but I have to say something on his code.

This does **ONLY** work if you do not run this code as user root. When you run it as root **EVERY** password for a known user is accepted.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

**EDIT:** 
To solve this problem you should use the `sudo` pam service intead of the `su` service with `pam_start()`